# Preparation for an Exam in Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am preparing for an exam in Probability and I have the two following questions.
First: let $\{X_{n,k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a collection of identically distributed and independent random variables that have a variance $\sigma^2>0$ and a mean $\mu >0$. 
Let $p_0=\mathbb{P}(X_{1,1}=0)$ and define $Z_0,Z_1,...$ by: $Z_0=1$ and $Z_n=X_{n,1}+X_{n,2}+...+X_{n,Z_{n-1}}$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now I need to show that: $\mathbb{E}(Z_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_n)=\mu^2Z_{n}^2+\sigma^2Z_n$, for $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(Z_0,Z_1,...,Z_n)$. 
I have already shown that $M_n=Z_n/\mu^n$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_n)-martingale$, since: $\mathbb{E}(Z_n/\mu^n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=1/\mu^n\mathbb{E}(Z_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=1/\mu^n(Z_{n-1})\mu=M_{n-1}$.

The second exercise asks me to show that if $X_\lambda$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\theta\lambda$, then $X_\lambda/\lambda$ converges in probability as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ and to determine the limit.

I have already calculated the characteristic function of $X_\lambda$ to be:

$\phi_{X_\lambda/\lambda}=\mathbb{E}e^{iuX}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\theta\lambda)^k/k!e^{-\theta\lambda}e^{iuk}=e^{\theta\lambda(e^{iu}-1)}$.

Comment: For future reference, it's probably better to only ask one question per post (which is not to say that you should only post one question, feel free to post as many as you like!) to keep the site nicer and increase the likelihood that you'll get answers to both.

Comment: Ok, I will do so from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Doing your computations more carefully, one gets $\phi_{X_\lambda/\lambda}(u)=\exp(\theta\lambda(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iu/\lambda}-1))$. One knows that $\mathrm e^z=1+z+o(z)$ when $z\to0$, hence, using this for $z=\mathrm iu/\lambda$, one sees that $\phi_{X_\lambda/\lambda}(u)\to\mathrm e^{\mathrm iu\theta}$ for every fixed $u$, when $\lambda\to\infty$. This proves that $X_\lambda/\lambda\to\theta$ in distribution as $\lambda\to\infty$. The limit is deterministic hence $X_\lambda/\lambda\to\theta$ in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the first part of your question. Since you have deduced that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{n+1}{}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right]{}={}Z_{n}\mu\,,
$$

then, observe that, because $Z_{n}$ is determined by the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$ and the $X_{n,k}$ are independent and identically distributed, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{V}ar\left(Z_{n+1}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right)&{}={}&\mathbb{V}ar\left(\left. \sum\limits_{i=1}^{Z_{n}}X_{n+1,i}\right|\mathcal{F}_n \right)\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{i=1}^{Z_{n}}\mathbb{V}ar\left(X_{n+1,i}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right)\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{i=1}^{Z_{n}}\mathbb{V}ar\left(X_{n+1,i}\right)\newline
&{}={}&Z_{n}\sigma^2\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Which means that,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z^2_{n+1}{}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right]{}={}\mathbb{V}ar\left(Z_{n+1}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right){}+{}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{n+1}{}\left|\mathcal{F}_n \right.\right]\right)^2{}={}Z_{n}\sigma^2{}+{}Z^2_n\mu^2.
$$