# How to show $\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}^{2} | \mathcal{F}_{n}) = \mu^{2} Y_{n}^{2} + \sigma^{2} Y_{n}$? (Unanswered repost)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, filtrations

I'm basically asking an extension of the first part from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089807/preparation-for-an-exam-in-probabilities) post a while back. To parse, it asked:

Given a branching process $Y = \{Y_{n} : n \geq 0\}$ and the corresponding family of random variables for the process $\{X_{k, n} : n, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, suppose $Y_{0} = 0$ and for $n \geq 0$,

$$Y_{n+1} = X_{1, n+1} + ... + X_{Y_{n}, n+1}.$$

If $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X_{n, k})$ for any $n, k$, and $0 < \sigma^{2} = Var(X) < \infty$, then

$$E(Y_{n+1}^{2} | \mathcal{F}_{n}) = \mu^{2} Y_{n}^{2} + \sigma^{2} Y_{n}.$$ Show that this implies $G = \{G_{n} = Y_{n}/\mu^{n}\}$ is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^{2}$. I know how to show that $G_{n} = Y_{n}/\mu^{n}$ is a martingale wrt $\mathcal{\{F_{n}\}_{n}}$, but I can't figure this simple extension out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear, you are not asking how to show $E(Y^2_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = \mu^2 Y_n^2 + \sigma^2 Y_n$ (since it was answered in the linked post), but are asking how this result implies $G_n$ is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^2$?

Comment: @angryavian Right, sorry for the ambiguity. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Hint: If you hit the relation on the conditional second moment with the tower rule, you get an explicit recurrence for the $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}^2]$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}[Y_n^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$. Figure out the mean, and then solve out the recurrence to argue boundedness.